# Change port 9999 (and others)

Tags: couchbase

I've recently installed another software that uses the port 9999, so I'd need to change that port in CouchBase in order to run both at the same time. I've seen the link that shows how to customise some ports (http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Install/user-defined-ports.html) but I couldn't find 9999 in there. It's specified here (http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/install/install-ports.html) but i'd need the exact name of the port to change it, if it is even possible.

Any clues ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The name of the port that binds to 9999 by default in Couchbase is: `projector_port` and you can configure it by setting it in the `static_config` as described in the first of your links by using that port name. So you'd add the following to the `static_config` file:

```
{projector_port, <desired-port>}.
```

where `<desired-port>` is the port that you wish to change to.

This only works on a fresh install -- if you already have a running instance you'll need to change the default value which has already been saved to the persistent configuration. You can do this as follows:

```
curl  -u Administrator:<password> http://host:8091/diag/eval -d "ns_config:set({node, node(), projector_port}, <desired-port>)."
```

You'll need to shutdown and restart the system for this to take full effect.

Comment: Ha, but that means I need to first run the server in order to change the persistent configuration, right ? Which in my case I can't do without an administrator... thanks anyway for the port name ! :)

Comment: Well if you go the route of adding to the `static_config` then you don't need to provision your server and then change the port. If you're system is already provisioned and you want to keep the data or setup, the `diag/eval` should do it for you.